# Powershell: How to RETURN a system.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox.Text + String value Together

Tags: powershell

Code has been summarized

```
$Input_List = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox
$Display    = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox

Function getUserInput {
return $Input_List.text
}

Function getIPconfig {
return Test-Connection $Input_List.Text.ToString() -Count 1 -Quiet
}
```

Here I would like to have the function setDisplayText to set the $Display with a value like "192.168.0.1" True

```
Function setDisplayText{
$Display.Text = $Input_List.Text + getUserInput
}
```

Comment: Since `System.Windows.Forms.RichTextbox.Text` returns a string it should work, it might be a problem with the user input I'd recommend seeing the value that is from it. Try doing `$Display.Text = "$Input_List.Text " + (getUserInput).ToString()`.

Comment: `"$Input_List.Text "` doesn't work. You have to use subexpression to use properties of an object inside quotes. `"$($Input_List.Text )"`.

Answer (score 0):

Try below, call both the function in `setDisplayText` function. String formating will help you to get quotes around the ippaddress.

```
Function setDisplayText{
    $Display.Text = "'{0}' {1}" -f getUserInput,getIPconfig
}
```